# TypeError: must be str, not StringField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

The script is suppose to take input from form module ie forms.py and stored in userToFind.username in routes.py which is a StringField.

So i convert StringField into string but it still doesnt work.

forms.py

```
class UserRequired(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

routes.py

```
def result(url, site, username):
    address = (url+username)
    try:
        headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"}
        r = requests.get(address, headers=headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=False)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return 1 #(site+" Account found on "+address)
        #else: return (site+"Account not found on"+address)
    except: return "error"

@app.route("/findUsername", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def findUsername():
    userToFind = UserRequired()
    if userToFind.validate_on_submit():
        usr = str(userToFind.username.data)
        for url,site in sites.items():
            if(result(url,site,usr+"/")):
                foundSite.update({url:site})
        return redirect(url_for('foundAccount'))
    return render_template("findUsername.html",userToFind=userToFind)
```

findUsername.html

```
{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

 <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ userToFind.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ userToFind.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}                    
                    {% if userToFind.username.errors %}
                        {{ userToFind.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in userToFind.username.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ userToFind.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ userToFind.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

builtins.TypeError

TypeError: must be str, not StringField
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

raise value

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

raise value

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/home/adil/anaconda2/envs/scapweb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/adil/scrapperProject2/scrapperproject/routes.py", line 106, in findUsername

for url,site in sites.items():

File "/home/adil/scrapperProject2/scrapperproject/routes.py", line 49, in result

address = (url+username)

TypeError: must be str, not StringField
```

Comment: What's in `sites`?

Comment: just a site url - sites = {"https://www.instagram.com/": "Instagram"}

Comment: oh got it, changed redirect(url_for('foundAccount')) to correct method name for @app.route()